# HTML img src not absolute

Tags: html, image

I have an image within an iframe:

```
<img src="www.******.co.uk/payroll3/images/member.png" height="100" width="100">
```

The image doesn't load, when I select the image address when its run in the browser it shows that it is trying to get the image from the directory below rather than the one specified in the img tags.

```
http://www.****.co.uk/payroll3/backend/www.asmserver.co.uk/payroll3/images/member.png
```

It appears to be appending a base url..

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I stop this from happening?

Comment: Please note that something like `www.******.co.uk/payroll3/im.....` is NOT a valid URL. A typical case where browser features trying to make things more simply for users lead to people not even realizing any more that there is a difference between a "domain name" and a URL.

Comment: You need `http://` in front

Comment: @askasha well, technically it is valid - but it points to a subdirectory named `www.*****.co.uk`

Comment: thanks @Pekka웃 thats solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use fully qualified web address with "http://" or "https://" if its secure that will solved your problem like,

```
<img src="http://******.co.uk/payroll3/images/member.png" height="100" width="100">
```